# Shape keys aren't properly exported to Unreal Engine 5

Tags: animation, export, shape-keys, .fbx, unreal-engine

I have a problem about exporting shape keys from Blender to Unreal Engine 5 (morph targets).

[image: Blender model photo]

This is my model made in Blender. It includes three shape keys: blinking, mouth closed, and mouth laughing. I also made a Driver to control the blinking shape key where the Shape Key is controlled by the y-position of the bone in front of the character's left eye.

[image: Unreal engine photo of model]

I have followed a lot of tutorials online and was informed that all shape keys can be imported by ticking the *Import Morph Targets* when importing to UE5. I did do that, but I ended up imported nothing and the mouth of the model imported to UE5 even deformed in a weird manner.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200602/im-trying-to-export-a-character-to-ue4-but-i-cant-seem-to-export-the-shape-ke

Comment: Yeah that solves my problem, thank you so much! I didn't know that the Apply Modifier option in the export tab removes the shape keys.

Comment: Good!  It's always worth searching for previous questions before asking! :^)